# Photo indexing software for Mac OS X 10.5.8 with the ability to upload to a photo printer / sharing service?

Tags: photos, graphics, leopard, photos.app

I want to scan old color slides using a Nikon Coolscan on Mac OS X Version 10.5.8.  I want a program that will allow me to index these files and add descriptions, dates, locations and other information.  I would like this program to upload to an image sharing service like Picasa, Flickr, or Shutterfly so that I can print them out and share them with others but also keep them private.  I don't want third parties to be able to copy and print them.

Comment: I assume that you are aware that once you moved an image onto the Web, other people *will* have access to it (even it it's marked private). And you won't be able to prevent your sharing partners from copying and printing at all.

Answer (score 1):

That's precisely what [iPhoto](http://www.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/what-is.html) is for.  Google has discontinued the Picasa exporter for iPhoto, but there are numerous other exporters including:

[Flickr exporter](http://connectedflow.com/flickrexport/), and [an exporter for Shutterfly](http://www.shutterfly.com/downloads/features_mac.jsp).